# Javascript function to load a DIV after the entire page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, load, loaded

I want to load the DIV "image" only after the entire page is loaded.

What JS code do I need?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="image">
    CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

I will call the function with :

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

Comment: you may make ajax call and setup the image class div content there.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the request call inside `ready` function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //after the entire page is loaded.
   // load the DIV "image"
   $.get('url', function(data) {
        $('.image').html(data);
   });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.image').fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  
    <!-- This will appear after image has been loaded -->
    <div class="image" style="display: none">
        CONTENT
    </div>
  
</div>

<img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-triangles-background_yB0qTG6.jpg">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Am I blind, or your code doesn't work? Anyway, please comment your code..